# Cannot Get React Hook setInterval Timer to Run During Jest/Enzyme Test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, create-react-app

I am trying to write wrap up writing some tests for this component. I implemented a custom `useInterval` hook following this blog post from Dan Abramov ([code](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)). It basically makes a declarative `setInterval` function. However, I'm having a difficult time of testing it with Jest and Enzyme. The application was bootstrapped with create-react-app. I have installed the latest versions. When I click the start button, the elapsed time increases and displays on the page perfectly. In the parent component, I update state, which stores elapsed time. It passes the updated elapsed time `timer` props to `Timer.js`. Thus, it sows on the screen the correct `elapsedTime`. This works as expected in the browser. However, the timer doesn't run when running the tests.

```
// Timer.js
const TimerDisplay = ({ timer, updateTimer }) => {

  useInterval(() => {
    const delta = Math.floor((Date.now() - timer.offsetTime) / 1000);
    updateTimer({ ...timer, elapsedTime: delta });

  }, timer.isTicking ? 300 : null);

  const handleStartButton = () => {
    updateTimer({ ...timer, isTicking: true });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{timer.elapsedTime}</div>
      <button className='start' onClick={() => handleStartButton()}>Start</button>
      <button className='stop' {/* removed for brevity*/}>Stop</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

The test's code is below. I use Jest's spy function and enzyme's mount. I read that I needed to mount and not use shallow because of the hooks. I set Jest to use the fake timers. Then, I simulate a button press of the start button to verify that the button is working correctly. However, in this test, I've already set `isTicking: true` so I really wouldn't even need to simulate the start. Though it's a sanity check that the function spy works as expected - which it does. The expected result is that it calls the spy callback after 300 ms. Thus, when I `jest.advanceTimersByTime(500)`, the spy function should have been called at least once in the `useInterval` callback. However, this isn't occurring in the tests.

```
// Timer.spec.js
describe('Timer', () => {
  const spyFunction = jest.fn();

  const timer = {
    offsetTime: new Date(),
    isTicking: true,
    elapsedTime: 0
  };

  let wrapper = null;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Timer updateTimer={spyFunction} timer={timer} />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
    wrapper = null;
  });

  it('timer should run', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();

    expect(spyFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    wrapper.find('button.start').simulate('click', { button: 0 });

    // works as expected
    expect(spyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // doesn't seem to work for some reason
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(500);

    // will fail; function only called once by the button.start. It should have been called at least twice.
    expect(spyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

I'm thinking the issue has to do with the `useInterval` hook. I suspect garbage collection is happening before the callback is able to be called. Is there any way to test the `useInterval` hook's callback's calls `updateTimer` aka the `Jest.Fn`?

```
// useInterval hook
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `jest.useFakeTimers();`, more specifically in a place you call it. You are mounting your component in `beforeEach`, before you fake timers. Because of that your `useInterval` hook is set up to use real `setInterval`, not the faked on from jest. The moment you call `jest.useFakeTimers();` in a test is too late, as it wouldn't affect anything (you are not creating anything new related to timer).

If you move it before `mount` in `beforeEach` test would work.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure this out for the life of me. All my tests pass with 100% coverage.

Answer (score 0):

**try doing something like this**

```
it("should run the count until you get to 00:00", () => {
    loadWrapperAndInjectDependencies();
    jest.useFakeTimers();

    const resendOtpCode = wrapper.find({ testID: "buttonResendCode" });
    resendOtpCode.simulate("press");

    jest.runAllTimers();

    const timeText = wrapper.find({ testID: "resendCodeTime" });
    expect(timeText.props().children).toBe("00:00");
  });
```